# R str_extract everything before and after ellipsis

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to find a way to split a character column with an ellipsis in the middle into two columns, everything before the ellipsis and everything after.

For example, if I have:

```
a <- "60.4 (b)(33) and (e)(1) revised....................................46111"
```

How do I split that into "60.4 (b)(33) and (e)(1) revised" and "46111"?

I have tried:

```
str_extract(a, ".*\\.{2,}")
```

for the first part, and for the second part:

```
str_extract(a, "\\.{2,}.*")
```

but that keeps the ellipsis in both, which I'd like to drop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you want to *split*, not to *extract*, with a pattern that matches two or more consecutive dots:

```r
a <- "60.4 (b)(33) and (e)(1) revised....................................46111"
unlist(stringr::str_split(a, "\\.{2,}"))
## => [1] "60.4 (b)(33) and (e)(1) revised" "46111"                          

## Base R strsplit:
unlist(strsplit(a, "\\.{2,}"))
## => [1] "60.4 (b)(33) and (e)(1) revised" "46111"
```

There is another possible splitting regex here: you can match any one or more dots that are followed with a some one or more digits at the end of string:

```r
unlist(stringr::str_split(a, "\\.+(?=\\d+$)"))
unlist(strsplit(a, "\\.+(?=\\d+$)", perl=TRUE))
```

Both yield the same `[1] "60.4 (b)(33) and (e)(1) revised" "46111"` output. Here, `\.+` matches one or more dots and `(?=\d+$)` is a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with one or more digits (`\d+`) and then end of string (`$`).

Another approach is a *matching* one with `str_match` (to capture the bits you need):

```r
res <- stringr::str_match(a, "^(.*?)\\.+(\\d+)$")
res[,-1]
# => [1] "60.4 (b)(33) and (e)(1) revised" "46111"
```

Here,

- `^` - matches the start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\.+` - one or more dots
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

The `res[,-1]` is necessary to remove the first column with the full matches.